# Will users open an .ICS attachment?

Tags: email, best-practice, billing

When sending a bill to customers, we're considering including an ICS file that will allow them to add a calendar item for their bill due date, with a reminder.

- will users understand what this does and actually open it?
- should it be a one-time event or recurring event?

I'm concerned that we'll be adding complexity to the email for very little gain, since I think a lot of users won't really grasp the usefulness of the attachment. I know many email clients are better at handling these now and expose the calendar info in a friendly format, but will anyone actually use this capability to add a bill reminder?

I can't find any research or articles on this kind of case, but maybe someone has some insight.

Comment: What's the harm in trying it and seeing how your users behave?

Comment: This sounds like something you need to ask your users. We can only speculate.

Comment: There are email clients that understands ics Attachments and can present the events and add them an integrated calendar with a few clicks. Users that don't understand .ics and whose email client don't understand them either writes probably just ignore the attachments. You should still add all the details of the events on the email body and some blurb on the email body about what the attachment is about. The only other consideration is that the attachment adds size to the email, if you're doing a lot of emailing, this may be significant (but bandwidth is cheap, usually).

Answer (score 3):

There are better ways to add a calendar item

Assuming you want to give users the ability to add a calendar entry:

- **ICS attachments suck**.  (1) users may not know what an ICS file is; (2) users are suspicious of attachments; (3) ICS files are handled inconsistently across platforms; and (4) you don't know what calendaring system users are utilizing.
- **Provide a user experience, not a file**.  If you're delivering the bill via web, then guiding the user to add a calendar entry is much better.  See [this widget](https://addthisevent.com/) for example.  If you're delivering by email, you can add a `Add calendar reminder` button which takes users to web page with options to add to outlook, google cal, etc.  This also has the additional benefit of providing you with a measurable response to the button.

I can't speculate on whether or not you should offer this feature...that's a business decision.

Comment: I would argue on handling of ICS attachments. GMail, Yahoo, and Live Mail/Hotmail handle them very well. All desktop e-mail clients handle them very well, too. If users are in enterprise environment, their means of accessing e-mail is more than likely to support ICS extremely well.

Comment: @dnbrv from my perspective,  being able to open a file and providing a good user experience are slightly different in this case. People often have multiple and different email and calendar clients. I may receive a bill in Outlook at work, and want to put it on my family calendar in Google. Gmail presumptuously defaults to GCal. On mobile clients, ics files may default to the local Samsung or Apple handler app. From a user perspective. I prefer to give the user a guided experience to calendaring rather than open the possibility of a disorienting or frustrating experience

Comment: I agree with you that good UX is imperative. However, your example with Outlook is an edge case (and not a good business or personal productivity practice). However, the default calendar application on mobile devices is usually the place where the user keeps their personal calendar to begin with. That being said, it shouldn't be an either-or solution. Some people will know how to handle attachments while others will find a link to add to their calendar more useful.

Comment: I suspect it will be an either or decision in the sense that it'd be weird to have an email with an ics attachments and also a calendar link. But hopefully the OP has enough information to make a reasoned decision either way

Answer (score 0):

It often occurs, in order to keep simplicity we compromise some features that will really add value to our service.

So before taking any decision its better to know

1. The **level of understanding** of your user.
2. If majority your users are **smart enough** to detect ICS then I strongly recommend to add it.
3. If majority is not familiar with it then drop it.
4. And if you *don't have enough idea* about your users understanding then take the ***first campaign as a test***. And tune up your decisions.